# What's the significance of the 'w' finger position in Elfen Lied?

Tags: symbolism, elfen-lied

I've noticed that in the opening sequence, and the big climactic moment at the very end of the season, Lucy has her hands on the figure's back with the ring/middle fingers together and the other two fingers separated in a 'w' sort of shape.

Is this a symbol of love, a reference to Gustav Klimt (like the paintings) or something else?

I've also noticed it on the cover of the 3rd Vampire Bund Omnibus.

[image]

Comment: She's representin the west-side west coast

Comment: @JonLin she hit em up!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's likely to be a homage to the work of [El Greco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Greco), who used this hand symbol in his [various works](http://www.darkfiber.com/pz/chapter1.html).

Like this one titled *The Gentleman with His Hand at His Breast*

[image: The Gentleman with His Hand at His Breast]

or *Christ Carrying the Cross*

[image: Christ Carrying the Cross]

The meaning of this gesture is subject to much debate...

Some hypothesis [indicate](http://www.darkfiber.com/pz/chapter1.html) that:

> 1. The hand gesture is a secret sign indicating that the gentleman is a Marrano -- a crypto-Jew who accepted Christian baptism in order to remain in Spain after the Catholic Kings' order of 1492 that all Jews leave Spain;
> 2. The gesture indicates a Loyolan/Jesuit spirituality that calls for the sinner to place his/her hand on their chest after committing a sin as a sign of moral pain. Both of these theories have been discussed at length in academic circles without, however, formal acceptance of either, though at least one academic allows that the hand "assumes the function of an important communication, a personal avowal."

Comment: So like a religious connotation, like something sacred? I imagine it's used in the vampire bund to be more of a cool thing than in Elfin Lied

Answer (score 0):

It has been suggested the M symbol of the fingers refers to Mary Magdalene and the theory that they had a child. Knights Templar order and all that. Famous portrait (posthumous) of Christopher Columbus shows his fingers in this arrangement, various statues and paintings also show hands arranged this way. It's rather curious as it's not a natural way to hold your fingers. Some people say the Statue of Liberty, the hand holding the tablet also shows this arrangement. The Freemasons were involved in many of these things and it's said they are what remains of the Templars.

Comment: Do you have any sources for these claims?

Comment: Scott Wolter's America Unearth show on the History Channel. http://www.history.com/shows/america-unearthed/season-3/episode-12?cmpid=MRSS_tvguide_HIS and the book "The Templar Revelation: Secret Guardians of the True Identity of Christ" by Lynn Picknett and Clive Prince. A little google search will find other stuff.

Answer (score -1):

The hand gesture Lucy makes in official art and during the opening is prevalent in Loyolan/Jesuit spirituality, wherein those who commit sins are to place their hands on their chest with the middle and ring fingers joined to show moral pain and/or remorse for their actions.

Comment: This answer does not add anything that isn't mentioned in the currently accepted one already.